# Populating HTML Dropdown List using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I was practicing using HTML/PHP/MySQL, and was working on a small project.

I wanted to create a page that would allow the user to add records to a MySQL table.  The user would enter the values via an HTML form.  This data would then be posted to a php script to perform the actual INSERT INTO.

The database is for a shop, and has 2 tables, product and manufacturer.  When adding a product, I must also add a code for the manufacturer.  I want to populate a dropdown list, showing the names of manufacturers (taken from the manufacturers table).

I am attempting to embed this PHP code into an HTML file.  Here is the code:

```
                <form action="" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Enter Product Details:</legend>
                    Product Name:<input type="text" name="productName"><br>
                    Product Price:<input type="text" name="Price"><br>
                    <?php
                        $host="localhost";
                        $user="root";
                        $pass="";
                        $db="computer_shop";
                        $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Couldn't connect");
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM manufacturer";
                        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ("Could not execute query!");
                        if(!$result){
                            echo"Error with results";
                        }
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {         
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                $code=$row["Code"];
                                $name=$row["Name"];
                                echo"<select name='select'>";

                                    echo"<option value=" .$code.">".$name."</option>"  ;
                                <echo"</select>";
                            }
                            echo "<br>";

                        } else {
                            echo "0 results";   
                        }
                        mysqli_close($conn);

                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

When I attempt this, it doesn't go well.  When I load the page, the initial part of the form (with input boxes for name and price are fine), but the drop down list is a mess, and I see the code: "0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $code=$row["Code"]; $name=$row["Name"]; echo" along with a drop down list showing only $name, and then the submit button.  So the HTML file is displaying part of the actual PHP code.

My question is, how do I fix this so that the drop down list will display the values from the mysql database?  I have been looking through various sites, trying different things, but I keep getting a similar problem.  Should I flip things, and embed the HTML inside a PHP file instead?

Comment: If the php code is displayed, then either you do not have php installed, or the file is not configured to be parsed by php.

Comment: Thanks, I converted it to a PHP file, and put the HTML tags inside echo statements.  Got rid of that error and have it working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general this code is not a good practice. Make sure that this code is in a `.php` file and your web server supports php.

Other than that, I think that the following script will solve your problem.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   //open the select tag before the loop
   echo"<select name='select'>";
   //populate the select
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $code=$row["Code"];
      $name=$row["Name"];

      echo"<option value=" .$code.">".$name."</option>"  ;
   }
   //close the select tag after the loop
   echo"</select>";
   echo "<br>";
} else {
   echo "0 results";   
}
```